# Is the preference with SIMD to always get rid of branching?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, concurrency, simd

If you are writing some SIMD code that will be run by another program, is it always favorable to get rid of branching to increase performance? I heard that even doing extra operations just to avoid `if/else` statements, etc is still much faster.

I ask this because I have some branching that I do that's basically like this:

```
//  axis; x=0, y=1, z=2

float p, q;
if (axis == 0)
{
    p = point.y;
    q = point.z;
}
else if (axis == 1)
{
    p = point.x;
    q = point.z;
}
else if (axis == 2)
{
    p = point.x;
    q = point.y;
}
```

Can I avoid this kind of branching with some clever trick?

Comment: It really depends on whether the branches are predictable or not. If you call this function many times in a row with the same value for 'axis', then it's better this way. If `axis` looks random, then it's worth optimizing them out. If you can inline it in code that sets `axis`, then it won't matter since you won't get the branches anyway.

Comment: Thanks, the axis is fixed for all calls. Also by inlining do you mean just inlining the appropriate branch? If so, that would be sweet. I will check if the compiler does that.

Comment: If this function inlines, then the generated code should only have the taken branch. If this function is too big to inline, you may wish to make a version of the function for each value of axis (with only that branch) and then have a 'wrapper' function that does inline that selects the appropriate non-inline function based on the value of `axis`. The inline wrapper should eliminate the branch and call the correct branch-free function.

Comment: Also this is actually in the main function, not in a separate function. Does it matter if I separate it into another function or keep it in the main function? I thought it wasn't too big or generic and very related to the main function, as nothing else uses this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most SIMD architectures have special instructions which let you conditionally select elements based on a mask vector. The mask vector is typically the result of a SIMD compare instruction. So yes, it's pretty easy to get rid of the kind of branches that you have in your example above.

Whether you actually *need* to get rid of any given branch though will depend on various factors such as the predictability of the branch, the nature (statistics) of the data, and how much code is executed conditionally. As a rule of thumb, branchless is good, but as with most rules there are exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, actually the program calls my function knowing the value is fixed, but if I want I could make it dynamic in the program but even then the program would be aware that the value is not the same as it's the one calling my function. I am not sure if it uses this info though. Would printing something in the branches and see if it's printed once or for each entity/element prove the compiler actually optimizes this?

Comment: It's hard to give specific advice without knowing what CPU, compiler, etc you are using. Usually you want to look at the generated code (e.g. `gcc -S`) and/or use a profiler to identify performance bottlenecks.