# if condition in loop and neon SIMD

Tags: arm, simd, neon, cortex-a

I am trying to write the neon level SIMD for below scalar code :

Scalar code :

```
  int *xt = new int[50];
  float32_t input1[16] = {12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,};
  float32_t input2[16] = {13.0f,12.0f,9.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,13.0f,12.0f,9.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f,12.0f};
  float32_t threshq    = 13.0f;
  uint32_t corners_count = 0;
  float32_t threshq =13.0f;
  for (uint32_t x = 0; x < 16; x++)
  {
      if ( (input1[x] == input2[x]) && (input2[x] > threshq) )
         {
             xt[corners_count] = x ;
         }
 }
```

Neon:

```
   float32x4_t t1,t2,t3;
   uint32x4_t rq1,rq2,rq3;
   t1 = vld1q_f32(input1);       // 12 12 12 12
   t2 = vld1q_f32(input2);       // 13 12 09 12
   t3 = vdupq_n_f32(threshq);    // 13 13 13 13
   rq1 = vceqq_f32(t1,t2);       // condition to check for input1 equal to input2
   rq2 = vcgtq_f32(t1,t3);       // condition to check for input1 greater than to threshold
   rq3 = vandq_u32(rq1,rq2);     // anding the result of two conditions
   for( int i = 0;i < 4; i++){
    corners_count = corners_count + rq3[i];
   //...Not able to write a logic in neon for the same
   }
```

I am not able to write a logic in Neon .
Can anyone really guide me for the same .I am totally got tired in thinking about this logic

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902911/is-the-preference-with-simd-to-always-get-rid-of-branching

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for the link.But in my case I am able to use the Neon instructions to get rid of the condition but my concern is below :consider I am getting `mask` as `0 1 0 0` .then for mast 1 only I need to update the  `xt[corners_count] = x ;`means though I used a vector,`corners_count` should increased by one only .and xt should filled while mask is 1 not and zero .

Comment: the answer I linked to probably wasn't clear enough - the general idea is that you execute both branches into two temporary result vectors (one of each branch) and then use the mask to select the correct elements from each of these two vectors into the final result vector.

Comment: @PaulR,is it like  `if(mask[idx] = 0xffff){xt[corner_count] = x}`

Comment: Actually now I look at your original code more carefully I see that you can't do this in SIMD - you have a serial dependency on `corners_count` so you are out of luck. You can only do the branch stuff with masking in SIMD if there are no horizontal dependencies.

Comment: @PaulR thats very bad news .I was expecting some type optimisation in this code base .

Comment: You might be able to do it if you re-think your algorithm, but as it stands it's not SIMD-friendly. You probably want to break it up into two passes, the first pass would be SIMD and would generate a temp array of 1/0 values for pixels which pass the test, then you'd have a second scalar loop which iterates through this temp array, doing the corner_count stuff and storing the x values.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the dependencies in your loop I think you need to re-factor your code into a SIMD loop followed by a scalar loop. Pseudo code:

```
// SIMD loop
for each set of 4 float elements
    apply SIMD threshold test
    store 4 x bool results in temp[]

// scalar loop
for each bool element in temp[]
    if temp[x]
        xt[corners_count] = x
        corner_count++
```

This way you get the benefits of SIMD for most of the operations, and you just have to resort to scalar code for the last part.

Comment: Thanks for this answer .Its help me a lot .I want to ask whether it will give some performance ?Actually my algorithm having two for loops for height and width .So writing two for loops that is one with SIMD loops and other with scalar loop will give any advantage .Height 300 and width 400

Comment: The only way to find out for certain is to try it, but I would expect to see some benefit, since most of your operations will be in the SIMD loop. I've used a similar approach successfully in the past for cases where an algorithm could not be entirely vectorised due to dependencies and it has always been worthwhile.